# Cannot take DWT of parsed data

Tags: import, dataset, wavelet-analysis

I have some data in `foo.tsv`, and I would like to take the `DiscreteWaveletTransform` of one column. My data looks like this:

```
$ cat 2k-perp.tsv| head
Time    X   Theta   Field   Temperature Position
3681306328.25404644000  0.00000881875   7.77600000000   89999.99200000000   1.99810000000   0.00000000000
3681306328.75407505000  0.00000907021   6.11400000000   90002.19500000001   1.99890000000   0.00000000000
3681306329.25410414000  0.00000883924   7.71000000000   90000.74200000000   1.99930000000   0.00000000000
3681306329.75413275000  0.00000918104   5.97600000000   89826.46100000000   1.99900000000   0.00000000000
3681306330.25416088000  0.00000875542   8.15400000000   89893.00000000000   2.00310000000   0.00000000000
3681306330.75418949000  0.00000925275   4.96200000000   89823.42200000001   2.00490000000   0.00000000000
3681306331.25421858000  0.00000886811   7.86600000000   89719.32799999999   2.00420000000   0.00000000000
3681306331.75424623000  0.00000924530   4.66800000000   89654.82799999999   2.00190000000   0.00000000000
3681306332.25427532000  0.00000876567   6.82200000000   89587.88300000000   1.99700000000   0.00000000000
```

and I import it with the following Mathematica code:

```
dat = Import["foo.tsv", "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> 1]
```

Thus far, all good. But then when I call

```
DiscreteWaveletTransform[dat["X"], SymletWavelet[8]];
```

I get the error message: `Part X is not applicable to expressions of the form {__Association}.`

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify which rows to extract as well. To get the entire `X` column you can use `All`:

```
dat[All, "X"] // Normal
```

> ```
> {8.81875*10^-6, 9.07021*10^-6, 8.83924*10^-6, 9.18104*10^-6, 8.75542*10^-6,
>  9.25275*10^-6, 8.86811*10^-6, 9.2453*10^-6, 8.76567*10^-6}
> ```